Error while performing q2r.x (Phonon dispersion)
I want to plot the phonon dispersion of Au. I successfully ran pw.x and ph.x. (I am sharing the input files as follows). However, while running q2r.x, I have found the error " nc already filled: wrong q grid or wrong nr". Would you please see the inputs where I have made any mistakes?
&CONTROL
  calculation = 'scf'
  outdir = './out/'
  prefix = 'Au'
  pseudo_dir = './'
/
&SYSTEM
  degauss =  0.01
  ecutwfc =   100
  ibrav = 0
  nat = 1
  ntyp = 1
  occupations = 'smearing'
  smearing = 'mp'
  nosym = .TRUE.
  noinv = .TRUE.
/
&ELECTRONS
  diagonalization='cg'
  conv_thr =   1.0e-10
  mixing_beta =   0.4
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
Au     196.966569 Au_ONCV_PBEsol-1.0.upf
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
Au           0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000
K_POINTS automatic
15 15 15 0 0 0
CELL_PARAMETERS angstrom
   0.000000235   2.037568691   2.037568574
   2.037568691   0.000000117   2.037568574
   2.037568691   2.037568574   0.000000000

ph.x
&inputph
    amass(1) = 196.966569,
    prefix = 'Au',
    outdir = './out',
    ldisp = .true.,
    fildyn = 'Au.dyn',
    tr2_ph = 1.0d-14,
    nq1 = 4,
    nq2 = 4,
    nq3 = 4
/

After ph.x the output (Au.dyn0)
   4   4   4
  64
   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+00
   0.176776700415398E+00   0.176776690177877E+00  -0.176776720716921E+00
  -0.353553400830796E+00  -0.353553380355754E+00   0.353553441433843E+00
  -0.176776700415398E+00  -0.176776690177877E+00   0.176776720716921E+00
   0.176776700415398E+00  -0.176776710566160E+00   0.176776700328640E+00
   0.353553400830796E+00  -0.203882829508117E-07  -0.203882817573220E-07
  -0.176776700415398E+00  -0.530330090921914E+00   0.530330141762483E+00
  -0.277555756156289E-16  -0.353553400744037E+00   0.353553421045561E+00
  -0.353553400830796E+00   0.353553421132320E+00  -0.353553400657279E+00
  -0.176776700415398E+00   0.530330111310197E+00  -0.530330121374201E+00
  -0.707106801661591E+00   0.407765659016235E-07   0.407765635146440E-07
  -0.530330101246193E+00   0.176776730954443E+00  -0.176776679940358E+00
  -0.176776700415398E+00   0.176776710566160E+00  -0.176776700328640E+00
   0.277555756156289E-16   0.353553400744037E+00  -0.353553421045561E+00
  -0.530330101246193E+00  -0.176776669789594E+00   0.176776741105203E+00
  -0.353553400830796E+00   0.203882829508117E-07   0.203882817573220E-07
  -0.176776700415398E+00   0.176776710566160E+00   0.176776700415397E+00
   0.277555756156289E-16   0.353553400744037E+00  -0.203015242672411E-07
  -0.530330101246193E+00  -0.176776669789594E+00   0.530330141849240E+00
  -0.353553400830796E+00   0.203882829508117E-07   0.353553421132319E+00
   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+00   0.353553400744037E+00
   0.176776700415398E+00   0.176776690177877E+00   0.176776680027115E+00
  -0.353553400830796E+00  -0.353553380355754E+00   0.707106842177880E+00
  -0.176776700415398E+00  -0.176776690177877E+00   0.530330121460958E+00
  -0.530330101246193E+00   0.530330131698480E+00  -0.176776700241882E+00
  -0.353553400830796E+00   0.707106821876357E+00  -0.353553420958804E+00
  -0.883883502076989E+00   0.176776751342726E+00   0.176776741191961E+00
  -0.707106801661591E+00   0.353553441520603E+00   0.204750392474029E-07
  -0.353553400830796E+00   0.353553421132320E+00   0.867574900809132E-10
  -0.176776700415398E+00   0.530330111310197E+00  -0.176776720630164E+00
  -0.707106801661591E+00   0.407765659016235E-07   0.353553441520600E+00
  -0.530330101246193E+00   0.176776730954443E+00   0.176776720803679E+00
   0.353553400830796E+00  -0.353553421132320E+00  -0.353553400830794E+00
   0.530330101246193E+00  -0.176776730954443E+00  -0.530330121547716E+00
  -0.555111512312578E-16  -0.707106801488074E+00   0.406030485344822E-07
   0.176776700415398E+00  -0.530330111310197E+00  -0.176776680113873E+00
   0.530330101246193E+00  -0.530330131698480E+00  -0.176776700502155E+00
   0.707106801661591E+00  -0.353553441520603E+00  -0.353553421219076E+00
   0.176776700415398E+00  -0.883883512054234E+00   0.176776740931688E+00
   0.353553400830796E+00  -0.707106821876357E+00   0.202147667771602E-07
   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+00  -0.707106801488074E+00
   0.176776700415398E+00   0.176776690177877E+00  -0.883883522204995E+00
  -0.353553400830796E+00  -0.353553380355754E+00  -0.353553360054231E+00
  -0.176776700415398E+00  -0.176776690177877E+00  -0.530330080771152E+00
   0.176776700415398E+00  -0.176776710566160E+00  -0.530330101159434E+00
   0.353553400830796E+00  -0.203882829508117E-07  -0.707106821876356E+00
  -0.176776700415398E+00  -0.530330090921914E+00  -0.176776659725591E+00
  -0.277555756156289E-16  -0.353553400744037E+00  -0.353553380442513E+00
   0.176776700415398E+00  -0.176776710566160E+00  -0.176776700415397E+00
   0.353553400830796E+00  -0.203882829508117E-07  -0.353553421132319E+00
  -0.176776700415398E+00  -0.530330090921914E+00   0.176776741018446E+00
  -0.277555756156289E-16  -0.353553400744037E+00   0.203015242672411E-07
   0.353553400830796E+00  -0.353553421132320E+00  -0.867574900809132E-10
   0.530330101246193E+00  -0.176776730954443E+00  -0.176776720803679E+00
  -0.555111512312578E-16  -0.707106801488074E+00   0.353553441347085E+00
   0.176776700415398E+00  -0.530330111310197E+00   0.176776720630164E+00
  -0.176776700415398E+00   0.176776710566160E+00  -0.530330101072677E+00
   0.277555756156289E-16   0.353553400744037E+00  -0.707106821789598E+00
  -0.530330101246193E+00  -0.176776669789594E+00  -0.176776659638834E+00
  -0.353553400830796E+00   0.203882829508117E-07  -0.353553380355755E+00
   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+00  -0.353553400744037E+00
   0.176776700415398E+00   0.176776690177877E+00  -0.530330121460958E+00
  -0.353553400830796E+00  -0.353553380355754E+00   0.406898060245631E-07

q2r.x
&input
fildyn = 'Au.dyn'
zasr = 'crystal'
flfrc = 'Au.fc'
/

%%%%%%%%%%%%
The error message while running q2r.x is:
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     task #        36     from init : error #         1
       nc already filled: wrong q grid or wrong nr
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%      nc already filled: wrong q grid or wrong nr

Thank you in advance for your time.

I am guessing it has to do with the nosym = .TRUE. and noinv = .TRUE. keywords in the scf step. Can you check the number of k-points in the scf output? Why are you using them in the first place?

Hi, I have used it because I considered ibrav = 0, but when I use ibrav = number, then the problem is solved.

Even with ibrav = 0 you don't need to remove symmetries by hand. If you place your atoms correctly, you should get the correct number of symmetries, using ibrav = 0.

I got your point. Thank you so much!
